# Using a layout from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which has many associations. In the layout for this controller I have several submenus where I want to display objects from those associations. 
But how can I use this layout inside those objects? -i.e. There is no visibility for the other objects inside those controllers and therefore I keep getting the error "You have a nil object...." 
How can I use the layout inside the associated objects/persist the values of other instance variables inside those objects so that I can use the same layout inside all the submenus?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use more than one layout per Controller method.  The render method does take a :layout parameter, so you can specify one other than the default.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  Extract the layout bits you want to share into a partial.  Put it in views/application or views/layouts

Step 2.  Make sure you set the extra instance variables in the second controller - go see what's happening in the first controller to set them and replicate that.

Step 3.  Include the new partial in your template for the new page.

All should work nicely :-)